# combine query_string and must in elastic search node.js client

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm doing a [search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-6-5.html#api-search-6-5) query but combining "query_string" with "bool" because I want to match items that must the `tags` array field and that must match some query like `entity.color:green`, so I would do like

```
{
    body: {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "tags"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "entity.color:green"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "entity.color": "green"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "must_not": [{
                        "term": {
                            "tags": ""
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "tags": "[]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    size: 10,
    index: myIndex
}
```

but I do not get any result. The query without the `query_string` return the right items filtered, but when adding it no.
I'm running latest version of [elastic search node.js client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) 15.2.0

I have also tried the nested `bool/must` approach but it does not work

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
                "exists": {
                    "field": "tags"
                }
            },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "entity.color:green"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "entity.color": "green"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "must_not": [{
                "term": {
                    "tags": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "tags": "[]"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `"match": { "entity.color": "green" }` would be the same as `"query_string": {                                 "query": "entity.color:green" }` wouldn't it?

Comment: Basically yes bur somewhere I have found that both were needed, but thinking on it I guess no. Anyways removing the match does not make it working.

Comment: Remove the query string. It is just a shortcut for other operations (like match) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try writing query string like

query_string: {
field: 'color',
query: 'green'
}